# PHPUnit was not found in your include_path

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm searching for the solution for a day but i have no luck.

I already install Zend Framework on Mac OS 10.9, i also install PHPUnit via pear. But when i tried to create  a project it show up a message

---

Testing Note: PHPUnit was not found in your include_path, therefore no testing actions will be created.
This is my pear localtion: /usr/bin/pear
This is my phpunit location: /usr/bin/phpunit

---

Thank you so much!

Comment: What version of Zend Framework? If ZF2, PHPUnit can come in via a Composer dependency

Comment: Thank you @EddieJaoude !! i'm trying with Composer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you install PHPUnit?

It is "just" not included in your `include_path` - that is it.

You need to add it's base path to the Zend Autoloader - [here's how](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/using-zendloaderautoloader/).

`composer` is also an option as @Eddie Jaoude mentioned.

The main difference between using `composer` and `pear` is that `pear` installs its packages globally and you need to include them in your path (to load them). `composer` on the other hand installs them locally in the project in your vendors directory and **automatically handles auto loading for you**.

Comment: !! I just installed Composer in /usr/local/bin. Could you tell me how to make Zend works with Composer?